# Error en función mutate(), aplicada en un data frame creado a partir de vectores

Tags: r, dataframe, class, calculo

Antes que nada me gustaría aclarar que soy muy nuevo en lo referente al lenguaje de programación R, por lo cual me disculpo por cualquier error en mi terminología que use para poder explicarles el problema con el que me tope.
En ese sentido, lo que hice fue un data frame a partir de la creación de vectores, en total son 9 vectores. Este es el código que hice para eso:

```
eje1_1 <- c(100,100,0,100,0)
eje1_2 <- c(25,50,100,10,67)
eje2_1 <- c(50,66,100,30,98)
eje2_2 <- c(60,80,100,60,34)
eje3_1 <- c(20,100,100,67,65)
eje3_2 <- c(100,100,100,17,100)
eje4_1 <- c(56,100,100,74,99)
eje4_2 <- c(80,90,100,98,23)
eje5_1 <- c(100,10,100,100,56)

evaluacion_estructuras_enero <- data.frame(eje1_1,eje1_2,eje2_1,eje2_2,eje3_1,eje3_2,eje4_1,eje4_2,eje5_1)
```

Una vez creado el data frame, aplique la función mutate para que me genere una nueva columna que tenga el promedio de calificación por eje, el código es el siguiente:

```
data(evaluacion_estructuras_enero) %>% 
  mutate(ranking_estructuras_enero = (eje1_1+eje1_2+eje2_1+eje2_2+eje3_1+eje3_2+eje4_1+eje4_2+eje5_1)/9)
```

Al ejecutarlo, me vota el siguiente error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
In addition: Warning message:
In data(evaluacion_estructuras_enero) :
  data set ‘evaluacion_estructuras_enero’ not found
```

Les agradecería mucho que me puedan orientar, la verdad soy muy nuevo, pero tengo toda la intención de seguir aprendiendo y mejorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es este:

```
data(evaluacion_estructuras_enero)
```

`data()` es un función que se usa habitualmente para traer al entorno de trabajo, datos de algún paquete que por defecto no se cargan automáticamente, por ejemplo:

```
data("USArrests")
```

Con esto recuperamos el `data.frame` `USArrest` del paquete `datasets`. El problema es que en tu caso `evaluacion_estructuras_enero` ya lo tienes cargado en el entorno de trabajo, no necesitas usar `data()` si lo haces, el retorno será una cadena con el nombre `evaluacion_estructuras_enero` de ahí el error que obtienes, el `mutate` recibe una cadena y no un `data.frame`:

> Error in UseMethod("mutate") :    no applicable method for 'mutate'
> applied to an object of class "character"

Lo cierto es que la solución es la que ya te han mencionado, usar directamente el objeto como inicio del pipe:

```
evaluacion_estructuras_enero)%>% 
  mutate(ranking_estructuras_enero = (eje1_1+eje1_2+eje2_1+eje2_2+eje3_1+
                                      eje3_2+eje4_1+eje4_2+eje5_1)/9)
```

De paso, es más genérico usar directamente `mean()`, te evitas saber el número de elementos a sumar:

```
mutate(ranking_estructuras_enero = mean(eje1_1,eje1_2,eje2_1,eje2_2,eje3_1,
                                        eje3_2,eje4_1,eje4_2,eje5_1))
```

Por cierto otra forma más cómoda para no tener que escribir todas las columnas:

```
evaluacion_estructuras_enero %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(
      ranking_estructuras_enero = mean(c_across(eje1_1:eje5_1))
    )
```

Comment: Te agradezco muchísimo por tu explicación y recomendaciones, de verdad me sirvieron mucho. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Corrí tu código sin el `data()` del principio y me funcionó. Siempre que concateno operaciones con `dplyr` al principio pongo solo el nombre de la tabla, así:

```
evaluacion_estructuras_enero %>% 
mutate(ranking_estructuras_enero = 
(eje1_1+eje1_2+eje2_1+eje2_2+eje3_1+eje3_2+eje4_1+eje4_2+eje5_1)/9)
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, saludos!